# Can GWT use Raphael via JSNI?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, raphael, jsni

I need to do some client-side 2D drawing in my GWT app (nothing fancy, just draw a bunch of basic 2D shapes - circles, rectangles, etc.).

I don't believe GWT has a graphics/drawing framework, and so I was wondering if there was any way to use [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to somehow connect to the reputed [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) JS library and invoke Raphael from inside GWT.

If this isn't possible, can someone explain why and what my options might be?

And if this is possible, then consider the following Raphael code that draws a square:

```
paper = new Raphael(0,0,500,500);
var rect = paper.rect(x,y,width,height).attr({"fill":"white","stroke":"red"});
```

I want that JS code above to execute when a user clicks a button. Here is my GWT click handler:

```
@UiHandler("signInButton")
void onClickSignInButton(final ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    // ????
}
```

**How do I connect the two?**

Comment: There are already some projects that wrap Raphael, https://code.google.com/p/raphael4gwt/ and https://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/ (I have not tried them though)

Comment: If you are looking to compare other gwt draw libraries, GXT has a draw library (used to back its chart package) which supports both SVG and VML (and Canvas on the way), Emitrom has Lienzo (canvas-only, so no IE8, but supposed to be fast), and there is at least one or two D3 wrappers out there for GWT (again, no IE8).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Raphael class in JSObject class.

```
public final RaphaelJSO {
    protected RaphaelJSO(){}

    public static RaphaelJSO getNew(float a, float b, float c, float d){
        return getNewInner(a,b,c,d);
    }

    private native static RaphaelJSO getNewInner(float a, float b, float c, float d)/*-{
        return new Raphael(a, b, c, d);
    }-*/;

    public JSObject circle(int a,int b, int c){
        return circle(this,a,b,c);
    }

    private native JSObject circle(RaphaelJSO o, int a, int b, int c)/*-{
        return o.circle(a,b,c);
    }-*/;

}
```

Like wise you can wrap other classes and/or provide methods on them.

Then call this Java code as you would otherwise.

Comment: Awesome - thanks @amity (+1) - what about any configurations in my module's `gwt.xml` descriptor, or in my UiBinder's `ui.xml`? Any other configurations I need to make to connect the two? Where do I place Raphael.js? Thanks again!

Comment: you can place the link to Raphael.js as for any normal javascript file in your html page via <script> tag. Alternatively if you want to inject the Raphael.js file on the fly, then make a utility method which checks if typeof Raphael === undefined then writes the script tag.